# mounting multiple ext4 partitions in Android 7+

Tags: sd-card, mount, partitions, app2sd, ext4

I am doing away with `exFat` for my `Microsd card` after  all my pictures  decayed ,  corrupted and the directory was locked. I cant seem to write into a specific directory. `chkdsk` will just plain abort saying :

```
The disk does not have enough space to replace bad clusters
detected in file \WhatsApp\.Shared of name 1.
Corruption was found while examining files in directory \WhatsApp\ (6).
```

so I 'd like give a shot to `Ext4` partitioning that cheap `micro sd` card , not just 2 ( the standard `app2sd` and `sdcard1` design ) but 3. One for apps  and other 2 depending on the write activity , I  tweaked the block parameters etc. for each 
 
I am able to mount the partitions &   a `rooted Total Commander` can see them all 
BUT  other apps cannot see the partitions I created.As I understand `vold` helps other apps be aware of this. So How do I go about getting this 'formally' with sounding 'hackish'

what I did :

```
mkdir /storage/<my dir>
mount -t ext4 -o noatime,rw /dev/block/mmcblk(x)p(y) /storage/<my dir>
where x and y are variables from partitions file in the proc dir.
```

I read  about a `fstab.<phonename>` file out there that can be modified but it would be overwritten every boot.

even the 2nd partition that `app2sd`  ( or `link2sd`) creates can ONLY be approached as `root`. So prolly those apps that ask for `root` can see this stuff but other apps can write to it 
`Ext4` is `linux` .  Sounds like `Android` seems to ignore its own 'biological' kid `ext4` and instead recognize a stepson '`exfat / FAT` ' 

I am sure I am missing something here. Any ideas ?
I am `rooted` with `Magisk`  on a Galaxy j7 with of course `TWRP` ( 3.x) installed

[Print env o/p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRUDc.jpg)
[image: Mount o/p]

Comment: **BUT other apps cannot see the partitions**. Even with root access? Make sure this isn't because of Mount Namespace: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/200449/218526. Vold exposes only first partition on sdcard to apps. Try [vold-posix](https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Repo/vold-posix) if yours doesn't support Ext4. Directly writing to SD cards is restricted since KK or even before. Access you get is through SAF. Also may use `bindfs` (FUSE) to modify permissions of mountpoints so that apps can read the partitions, even from within `/sdcard` possibly (never tested though).

Comment: Ok just to clarify. app2sd Mount script puts script in magsik folder. On my phone magisk is at /sbin/magisk  folder  and I modified that manually to add the same logic now 2X more times for each additional partition. Strangely after I modified the script . After boot 2nd part & apps never showed up. I ran it manually and they all showed up . Also under TC I could see the additonal mount pts under /storage showing up as drives. Nothing changed AFAIK but now TC looks weird - all those Drives disappeared. After running script these pts under /storage will still be seen & su - TC can see it.

Comment: Coming to 2 other Q's from Irfan .Lot of common apps wont request root  access. I cant force em & they cant see these even if I invoke TC. By going to TC I can see all of them under /storage but invoking TC via System share - everything disappears. Your other Q Magisk is get to global namespace yes. That was the setting hitherto . HTH

Comment: Also my partitions are like these mmcblk1p1--> App2sd second partition

Comment: Also my partitions are like these mmcblk1p1--> App2sd second partition mmcblk1p2  user data part # 1 , p3 user data part # 2 ,- all Ext4. If vold exposes just  1st Part, how do I go about getting the other 2 "exposed" ?. How do I get vold-posix working. How do I use FUSE . My parts are under /storage and earlier like I mentioned they got 'picked up' & could be seen as separate drives .in TC . Now they show as folders ( mounted ) under /storage .  When the former situation existed I am not sure if apps could not access those ( prolly could .. my gallery app did ,

Comment: not   sure what caused the change of mind from separate drives .in TC to folders ( mounted ) under /storage. I know at that time app2sd use to give some alerts some of the apps are not mounted correctly should - use  the advanced op to recreate mount script  -->  click Y --> reboot. I wonder if at that time it moved the mount script location /

Comment: post the output of mount and printenv somewhere (pastebin) after mountscript

Comment: I dont see any place where I can paste the full o/p due to restrictions in #chars so I attached screenshots. Need to see that mount @ 300% I was able to read some - the file gets toned down in size & quality even if < 2mb  ( max allowed )

Comment: see pics attached

Comment: from mount what i can see your first partition is mounted twice. from printenv i can see you have knox?

Comment: Knox is disabled or removed. Prolly 1st