# app2sd link2sd nightmare ..all Fully Linked apps disppear

Tags: mount, partitions, app2sd, link2sd, ext4

One advantage in using [`app2sd`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjiuc-LibjjAhVJf30KHfXBBIAQFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dmobi.infolife.app2sd%26hl%3Den_IN&usg=AOvVaw18GLT8sHMYjESzs7twmMH7) ( or [`link2sd`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.link2sdplus) ) was that if all your apps are totally linked

when you swap out phones you would hope to 'carry' your apps with you and of course space savings to /`Data`

I know how `linking` works but my question is about how `app2sd` and `link2sd` "remember' how apps are linked.
I am facing a constant problem  where my `ext4` `partition` # 2 does not automatically `mount`. I have to do soft-reboot  or use "Mount 2nd partition" after the boot. It does not want to do this on runtime and after this only partially linked apps will show up. I am rooted via `Magisk` with `Global Namespace` turned on . 

One of the consequence of this  is if an app is 100% linked it Just disappears ...WTF ..whoa  ! what a waste of time linking. Why does is do that . What's happening under the covers ? 
Both these are clone apps but I have been using `app2sd` for sometime after `Link2sd` dev. wont reply to emails ( I had the paid version ) 

These apps store linking info into an `app2sd` database ...why then cant this info be preserved. All my apps that are 100% linked ( well to be precise those apps that have `apk` , and `Libraries ( lib )` linked as against `data` and `ext_data` and `cache` . So an `app` with `apk` linked and `data` , `ext_data` & `cache` on `internal` would still fall in the 'disappear' category  ) 
keep disappearing Those that are part linked will appear .

Comment: apps are still there, maybe just the links are gone. you can manually link again with `ln -s` it will be recognized from Link2SD. besides this you can place mount script in /data/adb/post-fs-data.d or /data/adb/service.d just mount your ext4 partition to /data/sdext2 on earlier stage. remember these apps are outdated and developed for low memory devices with android 2.3.6, you have a native ext4 partition meanwhile called adoptable storage

Comment: Hi Thx for revert. /data/adb is not there on 7. Also for my SD card which has ext4 partitions it will not recognize this and wants  to format it. For adoptable storage , It should have asked me if I want to use the card partition as adaptable storage. So I dont think ext4 is respected for adoptable storage ( else If you know how I can  get Android to recog. this  & convert it to adoptable storage do let me know)

Comment: the other Q is .. yes for a handful apps I can manually link how can I do this for a ton of them . Apparently link2sd ( in my case app2sd ) has a DB that stores all this info. so in case links are broken , the DB can help  ( ? I 'd assume so but Need confirmation) .. why then do all 100% linked apps disappear ?

Comment: post-fs-data.d is folder from magisk, sure you have it. why then do all 100% linked apps disappear? Probably sdcard mounted too late
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214233 adoptable storage can make your sdcard 50:50 (for example) one is vfat other is encrypted ext4 partition

Comment: problem with `adoptable storage` is that `ext4`  is not supported since I i n `rooted` I can use the ADB method and give any kind of mix I want... but the second partition it will create is a `fat32`..so coming back to my concern .. I would like to devote a separate third partition for all apps that are extremely write sensitive such as a WhatsApp. and and isolate it from my main partition. Idea behind this also has to do with `wear leveling algorithm` which I read is active in `micro SD` card - if file system is based on FAT cf `ext4` which is not based on any file allocation table  & so does

Comment: not support .this is an inference I drew but I am not sure if it can be assumed true
so now coming back to main Q  how do I get 3 `ext4's` mounted and all of them should be available to all apps for RW

Comment: i believe you can mount with correct uid/gid then it should be accessible without root. regarding Link2SD see my first comment. or checkout the vold stuff as suggested here https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214684/mounting-multiple-ext4-partitions-in-android-7#comment275059_214684

Comment: look in the output of mount how a fat32 partition is mounted from android, use the same uid/gid for your mount replacements. for apps they 'disappear' check `/data/system/uiderrors.txt`

Comment: seems the uid/gid mount parameters only work for vfat partitions